# How to enable a function when "close" button is pressed in jAlert

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect the page back when the user provides a wrong authentication credentials but after a jAlert pops up and exactly after the close btn of the jAlert is pressed but I am unable to do so. Please help me out with this task. Thanks in advance!!!

---

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

      $.jAlert({
                 'title': 'Authentication Error',
                 'content': 'Invalid Username of Password"!',
                 'theme': 'blue',
                 'btns': { 'text': 'close' }
                });
           });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jAlert plugin provides an `onClose` function that fires when the modal is dismissed. Define the behaviour you want within the function, for example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.jAlert({
             'title': 'Authentication Error',
             'content': 'Invalid Username or Password!',
             'theme': 'blue',
             'btns': { 'text': 'close' },
             'onClose': function(alertElem) {
                 // alert("Redirecting...");
                 window.location = "index.html";
             }
        });
   });
</script>
```

See the jAlert documentation at http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/.